# DataBinding in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: data-binding, windows-phone-7

Is there a guide somewhere showing an example of using ViewModels in a WP7 application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check out Laurent Bugnion's [EX14 - Understanding the MVVM Pattern - from Mix 10](http://live.visitmix.com/MIX10/Sessions/EX14).

Laurent is the author of the popular [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/getstarted/) with support for WP7

Here's another couple of posts that may be of interest.

[C#er : IMage: Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) Explained](http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2010/04/model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-explained.html)

[.NET by Example: Using MVVM Light to drive a Windows Phone 7 / Silverlight 4 map viewer](http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2010/07/using-mvvm-light-to-drive-windows-phone.html)

And this post gives you an overview of some of the MVVM Frameworks available.

[JAPF » Blog Archive » Discover and compare existing MVVM frameworks !](http://www.japf.fr/2009/11/discover-compare-existing-mvvm-frameworks/)

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely check those out.

Comment: No worries, btw, if you just want straight databinding without the "ViewModel" slant, check out Jesse Liberty's posts on his blog.

Answer (score 0):

While MVVM is really a great pattern (and will be even more important with Silverlight 5!), I would really consider twice if this is appropriate for your WP7 application.

Reasons:

- No "Command" property for ButtonBase (it's SL3! Command was new in SL4). Therefore no easy use of Commanding-Pattern. You need to use RelayCommands, DelegateCommands or similar.
- No Commanding-Pattern at all for items in the Application Bar (ApplicationBarButton or ApplicationBarMenueItem). Not even with RelayCommands, as the ApplicationBarItems do not derive from DependencyObject. :( (see http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2010/04/09/using-commands-with-applicationbarmenuitem-and-applicationbarbutton-in-windows-phone-7.aspx)
- Dealing with Background-Threads, Dispatcher, etc. can be really cumbersome together with MVVM.

That doesn't mean, you shouldn't use MVVM! 
But check out carefully, whether MVVM is a benefit for your project or an additional burden that makes depelopment over-complicated.

HTH